# MS SQL рекурсия зацикливание

Tags: sql

Можно ли как то игнорить повторяющиеся значения в рекурсии (CTE) иначе он просто зацикливается?
Есть ситуация что при рекурсии будет зацикливание:
Например:

```
 id  from_user  to_user  message
 1       1         3     some msg
 2       3         2     some msg
 3       2         4     some msg
 4       4         1     some msg
```

Я хочу пройдя рекурсией взять все 4 записи

```
 id  from_user  to_user  message
 1       1         3     some msg
 2       3         2     some msg
 3       2         4     some msg
 4       4         1     some msg
```

но что бы запись с id 1 (заново повторяющиеся) не входили в рекурсию более одного раза, иначе получается бесконечный цикл(до `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 100)` раз)...
Мне нужно взять эти записи иерархически...

Answer (score 1):

Мало что понятно.
Где запрос? Что должна делать рекурсия?

Кстати, по умолчанию выполняется максимум 100 итераций.
Если вы не будете использовать бесконечную рекурсию, то зацикливание вам не грозит.

Comment: Обновил, написал более подробнее...

Comment: Вижу две одинаковые таблицы.
Что вам дано, и что требуется получить?
Лучше примером, чем словами.

Comment: Мне нужно получить эти 4 записи ну так как в последней записи to_user ссылается заново на первую то получается бесконечный цикл... вопрос в том что бы вытащить эти 4 записи проигнорив повторный проход....

Comment: Следите за id, например, чтобы он не убывал.

Comment: точно чёта я даже и не подумал про него!)